# Metric concept analogous to ultra metric for minimum

Tags: metric-spaces

It is known that a metric space is called non-Archimedean (ultra-metric) if $d(x,y)\le\max(d(x,z),d(z,y)).$ Just out of curiosity, does there exist any metric concept such that $\min(d(x,z),d(z,y))\le d(x,y)~\forall x, y, z?.$ Will imposing such condition on metric spaces lead to any contradiction?

Comment: What happens if you take $x=y$?

Comment: I got it. Thanks